# Userlogin and maintaining session in Framework7 mobile web app

Tags: authentication, local-storage, webapi, html-framework-7

I am developing a `Framework7 mobile web app`, I want to let the user login, now since i am using the `WebApi` to authenticate the user, i am confused as to how to store the user session. Like in ASP.Net we simply do `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username)` and that creates the session of the user which can be access through `HttpRequest.Current.User.Identity.Name` to access logged in user.

Can anyone suggest, how should i go ahead with the WebApi, i have heard about using localStorage, so my initial thought is i would authenticate the user through WebApi and once the user is authenticated, through framework7 (jQuery) i would create a localStorage and store the user name in it (not password) and now whenever user comes back to this web, i would pull the username from the localStorage and automatic login user instead of asking him to login, since this is going to be a mobile web app, so probably he will use it on his mobile device hence it's secure to save only user name in localStorage and auto login him.

Is the above approach appropriate, is there any downfalls of using it.

If yes, would it be ideal to check for Global page:init function for the user session, if found, then auto login him.

Answer (score 0):

This is a seriously flawed approach, because if one figures out that his account is identified by username in `localStorage` and is aware of some other usernames, then he could perform identity theft.

In general it's MUCH better to use a session id for this purpose, provided that:

- session ID is random-enough, certainly not a consecutive set of numbers
- session ID is temporary
- if user credential changes are issued, then you need to ask for a password

You could store the username inside `localStorage`, but you should never trust it on your server-side without validating. Browsers are nicely storing cookies for this purpose. If you for some reason cannot use this built-in feature, or you do not have a session ID at hand (I'm not well-versed in the technologies you use), then, in worst-case-scenario you could generate a session ID on the server at login time and make sure the client-side gets it in the response.

Comment: Can you please explain how i should go about with creating SessionID using WebApi, considering my API is hosted on another domain (same server though). like my main domain is xyz.com then the API would be api.xyz.com, i have enabled CORS so accessing api is not an issue, but i am afraid if i create session ID, it will be created on api.xyz.com and not on xyz.com

Comment: @Abbas there are several possible approaches. The first approach is that the API would only be reached to from your main domain (and you would build into your API a validation for that) and therefore anything your API would receive from your main domain would be trusted and the browser would only maintain a session for your main domain. The second is that your main domain would reach out to your API to generate an API session id upon login and send that back to your browser, which now would be aware of the API session.